# Accelerate font transfer speed on web page loading

Tags: asp.net

I got a web site (ASP.Net web form hosted on IIS7) that is getting slow to load. If I remove all image of the loading time, the things that got the bigger part of time is the loading of the font file (.woff in Chrome).

I activated the gzip compression in my Web.config but the speed is still slow.

Is there anything else I could do to speed up the transfer of the font files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server the fonts from a different site (domain/virtualhost) setup specifically for static files.  Serve the fonts from a CDN, or if is a common font, see if it already on a CDN, so that it might already be cached by the browser.  Since WOFF is already compressed, enabling compression may not add anything.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer @Zoredache gave, which is right on the money, might I also recommend the Google Font API. If the font you are trying to use is available it is a great way to add performance without having to set up a server for hosting static files or going through the expense of a CDN. A cool feature they just added is the ability to only return the characters you need in the font file. So, if it's just a simple string you are printing such as "Header 1" it will only return those characters in the font file, thus making it much smaller.

More information can be found at the following link: http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/

Comment: Thank for the information. But unfortunately for me the required font is not available on the Google Font API.

Comment: Aw, that's too bad. Well, something to keep in mind for future projects I guess. Good luck.